# Javascript else if statement rules not firing

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am using this tutorial from https://www.formget.com/jquery-login-form/

All is exactly as per the tutorial. But the else if statement doesn't seem to fire when the php script echo is 'Successfully Logged in...'. The text is an exact match for the else if statement. Anyone any idea why this doesn't trigger?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        // Checking for blank fields.
        if( email =='' || password ==''){
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("border","2px solid red");
            $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css("box-shadow","0 0 3px red");
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        }else {
            $.post("login.php",{ email1: email, password1:password},
            function(data) {
                if(data=='Invalid Email.......') {
                    $('input[type="text"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
                    $('input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
                    alert(data);
                }else if(data=='Email or Password is wrong...!!!!'){
                    $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid red","box-shadow":"0 0 3px red"});
                    alert(data);
                } else if(data=='Successfully Logged in...'){
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                    $('input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').css({"border":"2px solid #00F5FF","box-shadow":"0 0 5px #00F5FF"});
                    alert("W" + data);
                } else{
                alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: so ... which `alert` DOES fire?

Comment: The very last else statement. If php passes Successfully Logged in... the else if would display an alert WSuccessfully Logged in... but the alert is Successfully Logged in...

Comment: and exactly what does it say? please use `console.log(data, data.length)` as well ... then check your DEVELOPER tools console to check the exact value and length (should be 25) are what you expect

Comment: Getting an error. [Violation] 'readystatechange' handler took xxxx

Comment: what's that got to do with the length of `data`?

Comment: console.log(data, data.length) returns "Successfully Logged in...
 27"

Comment: I think there should be only 25 characters: `console.log('Successfully Logged in...'.length);`. Possibly some extra spaces in the PHP string.

Comment: Just been looking at that. I have changed the php to echo "x"; and now it is 3 characters long when it should be only 1. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: what does `console.log(data.charCodeAt(0), data.charCodeAt(1), data.charCodeAt(2))` output ... `254, 255, 120` or `255, 254, 120` perhaps?

Comment: 120 13 10. but this is with echo x

Comment: 83 117 99 when passing Successfully Logged in...

Comment: oh ... 120 13 10 ... I'm a derp ... of course ... echo outputs cr-lf (13, 10 respectively) ... try `data = data.replace('\r\n', '')` before your first `if`

Comment: Yes that did it. Nice one. Thanks